# Fixed size of div

Tags: html, scroll, fixed

I have added a scroll bar to my div tag. However, the size of this window dynamically grow according to the text size, and therefore the scroll bar is disabled.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;width: 650px;font-size: 14px;margin-top: 50px;display:None" id="loader" class="tr-bg tr-internal-frame" onclick='$("#workNow").toggle()'></div>
```

I guess that i need to fix the size of the window, and then the scroll bar will be enabled. Is it right? If so, how can i do that?

Comment: Take a div, inside a div. Give a fix height to the outer div. And apply overflow scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmgvyuh/. If you like the answer, lemme know, i will put as the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `div` a fixed `height`. Try this:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;width: 650px; height:100px; font-size: 14px;margin-top: 50px;display:None" id="loader" class="tr-bg tr-internal-frame" onclick='$("#workNow").toggle()'></div>
```

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xstzLmax/) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `height` in css of div tag..
try this code

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px; //ADD THIS
  width:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
a
b
c
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l

m
o
p


z
.
.
.

</div>
```